# Javascript create an Object based on specific Class Properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, properties, createobject

I want to instantiate an Object with existing Properties of the current Class in an easy way.

Somehow I still couldn't find an answer on the Net.

This is how I would expect it to be. Please provide me an easy Answer if there is any.

```js
class user {
    @observable username = '';
    @observable email = '';
    @observable password = '';
    @observable gender = '';

    @observable errors = {};

    @action
    submitRegister() {
      const userData = {
        username,
        email,
        password,
        gender
        }

        Axios.post('/api/users', userData).then(this.recieveMessage,this.recieveErrors);
      }
}
```

If I do the following for every Property it works, but I guess there is a shorter answer. At least I hope so.

```
const userData = { [this.username]: this.username, ...}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `{username: this.username, …}`, not `{[this.username]: this.username, …}`.

Comment: @Bergi well both do work but they are too long. I thought there must be a faster way

Comment: No, I am saying that the second one does in fact not work.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your shorter answer hope and your attempt with:

`const userData = { [this.username]: this.username, ...}`

Instead, try spreading `this.username`, like so:

`const userData = { ...this.username }`

Also try spreading `this`, like so:

`const userData = { ...this }`

Comment: const userData = {
            ...this.username, ...this.password, ...this.email, ... this.gender
        } doest not work.... sadly

Comment: Also try spreading `this`, like so: `const userData = { ...this }`

Comment: but then i got EVERY class attribute in the object... i just wanted to have specific ones :D but okay, guess this doesnt work easy

Comment: You either have to spread each specific class attribute or spread all of them.  If you prefer to spread all of them, consider an sub class which has only the things you want to spread.